# IIS 7.5 -Add Managed Module For .net 4.6.1 dll does not work-Could not load Dll error

Tags: c#, .net, dll, iis-7.5, httpmodule

My DLL project is built in 4.6.1 .net Framework.

I am using the App pool of V4.0.30319 and mode is integrated mode.

I did try to add the managed module in iis7.5 using the below steps:

1. Create the .NET 4.0 Class Library, and compile it as a strong named assembly
2. Install it in the .net 4.0 GAC by using the gacutil, located in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
3. Add this line under `<modules>` in applicationHost.config:

   ```
   <add name="MyName" type="NameSpace.ClassName" 
   preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
   ```

This makes the module run on requests to sites developed in .NET 4.

It appears, however, that requests to sites developed in pre .NET 4 versions can't use a module created in .NET 4.0

I took the reference of a thread https://forums.iis.net/p/1187109/2014938.aspx but this article did not solve my problem.

I am still getting the error "could not load the assembly".